# Android/Adobe air crash report: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, air, dalvik

i am getting this error inside Google's "Crashes & ANRs". The application built with Adobe Air and packaged as captive runtime.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeSurfaceCreated
at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeSurfaceCreated(Native Method)
at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(AIRWindowSurfaceView.java:719)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:545)
at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:693)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1731)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2583)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anybody know what this means?

Comment: Here is the Adobe bug, please vote on it: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3598923

Comment: could you find any workaround for this error? Im having exactly the same error after I include runtimeClasses.jar, and it was for integrating the use of AndroidActivityWrapper class.

Comment: This can happen if you are trying to load an AIR app on the emulator.  It has happened to me.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` for Java usually means that you tried to load a library called `nativeSurfaceCreated`.  Basically your code called a method that called a method and so on, and some code somebody else wrote called a native method.  This native method loaded a library called `nativeSurfaceCreated`, which you don't have.  This is usually packaged in a dll in Windows or a so file in Linux.  If you can find this dll/so file, you can probably run whatever you're running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not help me - my bad, did not explained the problem. This is Adobe Air library, which is a part of the application. The error is a part of the android-to-air connection, not missing files.

Comment: Sorry. I just was interpreting what I saw... I haven't extensively used android.